# Assign Click Events to < li > in JQuery Treeview

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, treeview

I am using the JQuery Treeview plugin to display some data.  Basically, I would like to add a click event to the child < li > elements that copies their innerhtml into another div on the page. I have not been able to assign a click event to these < li > elements however.

Hoping someone has tread this ground before and can provide some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just:
("#nameOfLi").click(function(){alert('foo');});?

Comment: yes - It doesn't seem to attach the click even for me. The same code will attach a click event to elements anywhere on the page outside of the treeview (obviously).

Comment: Could you post a code snippet?

Answer (score 6):

Using the markup from the example at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview:

```
$("span.file, span.folder", "#example li")
    .click(function() { alert($(this).text()); });
```

works.  Handling the click on the LI items themselves captures branch contractions and expansion.

Comment: Thanks, your comment made me realize it was the way I building the treeview (via JSON and adding branches)that was causing the issue.  I was able to resolve my issue by assigning the click event right after I had added the dynamically generated branches.

Answer (score 6):

You can use .live construction. For me it works:

```
$('li','ul#menu').live('click', function(){
    alert('Click event');    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li onclick="selectNode(event, this);" id="${node2.nodeId}" class="closed">
    <span class="folder"> ${node2.name} </span>
</li>




function selectNode(event, nodeHtmlEl) {
    // IE
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        window.event.cancelBubble = true; 
    }
    if(event.stopPropagation) { 
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    alert("selectNode ID: " + $(nodeHtmlEl).attr("id"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('li:not(:has(>ul))', 'ul#menu').live('click', function () {             
                alert($(this).text());
            });
```

it will add click event to leaf node only (not root node)